# Use if statement to modify row value

Tags: python, string, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataframe `ddd` with a field `date` containing  messy date values as text:

```
ddd= pd.DataFrame([["80's of 1900"], ["80's of the 19th century"], ["90's of the 18th century"], ["1955"], ["1822"]], columns=['date'])


In [2]: ddd
Out[2]: 
index date
0     80's of 1900  
1     80's of the 19th century  
2     90's of the 18th century
3     1955
4     1822
```

What I'm trying to do is to transform text values to a year like in row 3 and 4 for further analyses.
To do so in wrote a for loop with an if statement to differentiate rows like 0 and 1, 2.

So far, I have a code that makes a numpy array of indexes where the field `date` contains `'s of` to iterate over those rows:

```
selected_index = ddd[ddd["date"].str.contains('\'s of')].index.values
```

And a for loop with some regex to rearrange numbers in the string and to change '80's of 1900' to 1980 and '90's of the 18th century' to 1790:

```
for index in selected_index:
    if ddd.at[index, 'date'].str.contains('th century')]:
        num = re.findall('[0-9]', ddd.at[index, 'date'])
        num2 = ''.join(num)
        num3 = str(num2)[2:4]
        num4 = int(num3) - 1
        num5 = str(num4)
        num6 = str(num2)[:2]
        ddd.at[index, 'date'] =  num5 + num6
    else:
        num = re.findall('[0-9]', ddd.at[index, 'date'])
        num2 = ''.join(num)
        num3 = str(num2)[:2]
        num4 = str(num2)[2:4]
        ddd.at[index, 'date'] =  num4 + num3
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Expected output:

```
index date
0     1980 
1     1880
2     1790
3     1955
4     1822
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ddd.at[index, 'date']` is already `str`, so you can't call property `str` from it. To check if the value in it use `in`

```
if 'th century' in ddd.at[index, 'date']:
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the second line,

```
if ddd.at[index, 'date'].str.contains('th century')]:
```

[`.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) returns a value and the [`.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method is for a `pandas.Series`. You can use the `in` operator to check the condition,

```
if 'th century' in ddd.at[index, 'date']:
```